# Mysql transpose and group by

Tags: mysql

I would like to make a sort of transpose/groupby. I explain my case.

I have a table which look like that

```
p_qualifier                                          | p_value
-----------------------------------------------------|------------
|mooClassification/1.0/class-4.spherecorrectionlist  |+0.75
|mooClassification/1.0/class-4.spherecorrectionlist  |+1.00
|mooClassification/1.0/class-4.spherecorrectionlist  |+1.25
|mooClassification/1.0/class-4.spherecorrectionlist  |+1.50
|mooClassification/1.0/class-4.spherecorrectionlist  |+1.75
```

And I would like to obtain by a query (but i don't know if it's possible) something like that

```
p_qualifier                                          | p_value
-----------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------
|mooClassification/1.0/class-4.spherecorrectionlist  |+0.75; +1.00; +1.25; +1.50; +1,75
```

Thanks inadvance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT p_qualifier, GROUP_CONCAT(p_value ORDER BY p_value ASC SEPARATOR '; ') AS `p_value`
FROM table
GROUP BY p_qualifier
```

It will group column `p_qualifier` *(by same rows)* and `GROUP_CONCAT` will concat the result set of entire `GROUP` separating by the `SEPARATOR`.

Comment: thanks it works. Do you know a way to keep the sorting

Comment: you need to do this: `GROUP_CONCAT(p_value ORDER BY p_value ASC SEPARATOR '; ')` @user1859440

Comment: If you are in SQL Server the equivalent is STRING_AGG ( expression, separator ) [ <order_clause> ]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this:

```
SELECT p_qualifier, GROUP_CONCAT(p_value SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM testtable GROUP BY p_qualifier
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort `p_value`. Then use an `ORDER BY` clause inside `GROUP_CONCAT`.

**Query**

```
SELECT `p_qualifier`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`p_value`
ORDER BY  CAST((RIGHT(`p_value`, LENGTH(`p_value`) - 1)) AS FLOAT) SEPARATOR '; ')  
FROM `your_table_name`
GROUP BY `p_qualifier`;
```

Hope `p_value` is varchar.